# How to test DNS speed?

Tags: dns, benchmark

I am using google open DNS. 
How can I measure the speed of a DNS server?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You Can use the folllowing command:

```
  dig YOURDOMAIN +nssearch
```

Comment: `+[no]nssearch`    When this option is set, dig attempts to find the authoritative name servers for the zone containing the name being looked up and display the SOA record that each name server has for the zone.

Answer (score 30):

If you just want to time the lookup of a single record, use `time dig a foobar.com @8.8.8.8`. This testing method really isn't that good since after the first lookup, you'll be getting cached results and whatever server is closer to you will give you the fastest response.

[namebench](https://github.com/google/namebench) is probably the tool you're looking for. It does lookups based on domains are in your browser cache, random records from a list of popular records, etc. It is highly configurable to test your preferred list of DNS servers, your list of records, etc.

Comment: With DNS over HTTPS/TLS (DoH) `time dig +tls a stackexchange.com @1.1.1.1`

Comment: Note: For Ubuntu, `dig` support for `+tls` option started with [22.04 LTS](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/dig.1.html)

Answer (score 7):

This helped me on the bash prompt.  I had an issue where the name servers were randomly timing out.  You need the dig utility, which is not a default on minimal installs.  You can get it by installing

```
$ yum install bind-utils
```

for Fedora/RedHat/CentOS   or

```
$ apt install dnsutils
```

for Ubuntu/Debian

```
$ while true; do dig www.google.com | grep time; sleep 2; done
```

This yields an output like:

```
;; Query time: 2 msec
;; Query time: 1 msec
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; Query time: 1 msec
;; Query time: 53 msec
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;; Query time: 2 msec
;; Query time: 5 msec
;; Query time: 3 msec
```

On a healthy connection, it should be no more than 2 msec a query.

Answer (score 6):

## Using namebench

### Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install namebench
```

### MacOS

```
brew install namebench
```

### Example output

```
namebench 
...
> Sending 1 queries to 7 servers... [0/7]
> Sending 1 queries to 7 servers... [4/7]
> Sending 1 queries to 7 servers... [6/7]
> Sending 1 queries to 7 servers... [7/7]
> Saving report to /tmp/namebench_2019-08-13_1148.html
> Saving detailed results to /tmp/namebench_2019-08-13_1148.csv
> Opening /tmp/namebench_2019-08-13_1148.html
> Complete! SYS-127.0.0.53 [127.0.0.53] is the best.
Au revoir, mes amis!
```

Namebench will make an html report with the results of the best DNS for you based on response speed of the DNS server.

Comment: `namebench` does not seem to be available in bullseye (stable) anymore https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/namebench

Answer (score 5):

### 1. [dnsperf](https://github.com/DNS-OARC/dnsperf)

> dnsperf and resperf are free tools developed by Nominum/Akamai (2006-2018) and DNS-OARC (since 2019) that make it simple to gather accurate latency and throughput metrics for Domain Name Service (DNS). These tools are easy-to-use and simulate typical Internet, so network operators can benchmark their naming and addressing infrastructure and plan for upgrades. The latest version of the dnsperf and resperf can be used with test files that include IPv6 queries.

#### Building from Git repository

```
git clone https://github.com/DNS-OARC/dnsperf.git
cd dnsperf
./autogen.sh
./configure [options]
make
make install
```

#### NOTE

The binary file will be complied in `./srt` directory

#### simple config file

and the name of it is **data**

```
shakiba.net A
```

#### run the test

`-d data` is for config file (see above)

```
./src/dnsperf -s 1.1.1.1 -d data -c 10 -l 10 -Q 100
```

and this means

- `-s` source IP address == DNS server to query from
- `-d` read record from this file
- `-c` number of clients
- `-l` for this duration of time (10 seconds)
- `-Q` send this number of query

here 10 clients + 100 queries => 1000 requests

#### sample output

```
Statistics:

  Queries sent:         1000
  Queries completed:    1000 (100.00%)
  Queries lost:         0 (0.00%)

  Response codes:       NOERROR 1000 (100.00%)
  Average packet size:  request 34, response 87
  Run time (s):         10.075874
  Queries per second:   99.246974

  Average Latency (s):  0.083850 (min 0.080296, max 0.091041)
  Latency StdDev (s):   0.001694
```

### 2. [dnsdiag](https://github.com/farrokhi/dnsdiag)

> DNS Measurement, Troubleshooting and Security Auditing Toolset

> Ever been wondering if your ISP is hijacking your DNS traffic? Ever observed any misbehavior with your DNS responses? Ever been redirected to wrong address and suspected something is wrong with your DNS? Here we have a set of tools to perform basic audits on your DNS requests and responses to make sure your DNS is working as you expect.

#### use via Docker

```
docker run -it --rm farrokhi/dnsdiag /bin/bash
```

#### sample command

```
 ./dnseval.py -t A -f public-servers.txt -c10 shakiba.net
```

which means

- `-t` type of query e.g. `A`
- `-f` read config file
- `-c` number of query

#### config file

the file **public-servers.txt** contains list of DNS server to query from  e.g.

```
#Cloudflare
1.0.0.1
1.1.1.1
```

#### sample test + output

```
./dnseval.py -t A -f public-servers.txt -c10 shakiba.net
server      avg(ms)     min(ms)     max(ms)     stddev(ms)  lost(%)  ttl        flags                  response
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.0.0.1     7.301       6.502       11.736      1.566       %0       298        QR -- -- RD RA -- --   NOERROR             
1.1.1.1     6.816       6.195       8.433       0.622       %0       297        QR -- -- RD RA -- --   NOERROR
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this bash script:

```
#/bin/bash

DOMAIN=wikipedia.org;
echo "Tests common resolvers and calculates average response times by testing each resolver 3 times."
echo "************************"
echo "cPanel: 94.237.127.9"
echo "Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1"
echo "Level 3: 4.2.2.2"
echo "OpenDNS: 208.67.220.220"
echo "Google: 8.8.8.8"
echo "ANTEL: 200.40.30.245"
echo "Dyn: 216.146.35.35"
echo "Neustar: 156.154.70.1"
echo "puntCAT: 109.69.8.51"
echo "UncensoredDNS: 91.239.100.100"
echo "Hurricane Electric: 74.82.42.42"
echo "************************"
echo
for resolver in 94.237.127.9 1.1.1.1 4.2.2.2 208.67.220.220 8.8.8.8 200.40.30.245 216.146.35.35 156.154.71.1 109.69.8.51 91.239.100.100 74.82.42.42
do
   echo $resolver
   for reps in {1..3}
   do
    dig $DOMAIN @$resolver | awk '/time/ {print $4 " ms"}'
    sleep 3
   done |awk '/ms/ {sum+=$1} END {print "Avg time: ",sum/3, " ms"}'
   echo
done
```

Of course you can change the testing domain (in the example is wikipedia.org) and the DNS servers.

It returned this, in a test run:

```
94.237.127.9
Avg time:  14.3333  ms

1.1.1.1
Avg time:  2  ms

4.2.2.2
Avg time:  0.333333  ms

208.67.220.220
Avg time:  65.6667  ms

8.8.8.8
Avg time:  10  ms

200.40.30.245
Avg time:  0  ms

216.146.35.35
Avg time:  46  ms

156.154.71.1
Avg time:  5  ms

109.69.8.51
Avg time:  0  ms

91.239.100.100
Avg time:  210  ms

74.82.42.42
Avg time:  2.66667  ms
```

Answer (score 3):

Several of the above answers mention `namebench`. Despite being a useful tool, it is currently unmaintained.
It's successor is [naminator](https://github.com/mwiora/NAMEinator/), and unlike `namebench`, it is currently under active development. You may want to check it out.

Comment: This is no longer actively maintained, and the releases are broken.

Comment: The last commit on the repository is from 2 days ago at the time of writing. What do you mean by "actively maintained"?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you will audit possible DNS lookup delays that can happen when your apps try to access the database (with a possibly non-fixed ip), you can run this infinite script that monitors dns resolution every 5 seconds and appends the results to a file.

```bsh
while :; do { echo -n "$(date --rfc-3339='seconds') "; { time dig a db-host > dev/null ; } 2>&1 | grep real ; sleep 5 ; } >> /tmp/dns-latency ; done
```

Output in the file:

> 2021-12-08 14:31:25+02:00 real    0m0,002s
> 2021-12-08 14:31:30+02:00 real  0m0,002s
> 2021-12-08 14:31:35+02:00 real  0m0,002s
> 2021-12-08 14:31:40+02:00 real  0m0,002s
> 2021-12-08 14:31:45+02:00 real  0m0,002s
> 2021-12-08 14:31:50+02:00 real  0m0,003s